# Stuck at an exponential distribution assignment

Tags: probability

So I have a small question when it comes to probability and the Exponential Distribution.

The assignment states the following:

Clients arrive on a counter independently from one-another. The time between two arrivals has an exponential distribution with a parameter 1/6. Let X be the random variable that defines the time between two arrivals.

One client has just arrived on the counter. Find the probability that the next client will arrive for more than 15 minutes.

I think I know the answer but I'm not sure.

I think I'm suppose to solve P{X>15} but I'm not sure. Is this the right answer?

Comment: Do you mean, "will NOT arrive for more than 15 minutes"? If so, the answer is $e^{-15/6}$, which follows directly from the exponential distribution.

Comment: Yes that was what I meant. Is my answer correct?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the events we are concerned about are modeled by means of a random variable X that follows an exponential distribution with rate $\lambda=\frac{1}{6}$ (which expresses the frequency of arrivals per minute), to find the probability that the time that elapses between the arrival of two clients is greater than 15 minutes, indeed, you need to find $P(X)>15$.

(Although you do not ask about the solution, recall that the cumulative distribution function $F(x)$ of $X$ is given by $1-e^{-\lambda\,x}$. With that in mind finding the solution is straightforward).